# How can $\frac{1}{a/x-b/x}$ be equal to $\frac{1}{a-b}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

In an exercise asking to mark true or false, it shows:

$$\frac{1}{a/x-b/x}=\frac{1}{a-b}$$

It really look like **false** to me. But the answer is **true**! How can it be?

Comment: which books is this from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x\neq 0$, and $a\neq b$.  Multiplying top and bottom of the left hand side by $x$ shows $$\frac{1}{a/x-b/x}=\frac{x}{a-b}$$ and this equals $\frac{1}{a-b}$ if and only if $x=1$.

In short, it can't be true, but my guess is that the book meant to have an $x$ as the numerator of the right hand side of the original equation.

Comment: it really looks like the book's mistake..

Comment: I edited to indicate that.  Even books make mistakes from time to time.

Comment: One could also point out that they are not strictly equal-the RHS is defined at x=0, while the LHS is not

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is not $\frac{1}{a/x-b/x}=\frac{x}{a-b}$?  Otherwise I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1}{\frac{a}{x}-\frac{b}{x}} = \frac{1}{\frac{a-b}{x}} = \frac{x}{a-b} \not\equiv \frac{1}{a-b}$

So this is *not* true in the general case.